# Mailbox on different server, domain on my server. Windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, mail-server

I have one domain on my server and a mailbox (with the same domain ending) on a different server. I configured the mail and MX fields of DNS of that server to the proper value. All is working. But as I send an email from the website contact form (configured with SMTP = localhost) sending an email to the email address on the other server, the email will not reach the mail box ..Even no error is generated..Simply the mail server receives nothing. On the other hand from the contact form I can send email to different mailboxes.
How to solve this ?

Comment: Check your smtp server's log to see if/why the message bounced.

Comment: Checked it and for the log seems all to be normal. At first I admitted an error and created a mailbox info on the server which hosts the website and all the contact form emails were collected from the local mailbox and not sent outside to the internet. Then I removed the mailbox now it seems that the emails continue to not leave my server but even don't know where they are.

Comment: In mailenable I disabled the authentication relay ..may be this is the problem ?

Comment: My question essentially was how to say the SMTP server that the mailbox to which I sent is located outside the server and not on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting in the first panel for the SMTP settings in MailEnable, the host values to 200.x.x.x which should redirect all the traffic outside the server.